# HTML/CSS Position sticky is not working properly

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to make a div `position: sticky;` but it doesn't work, here's my code:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.top-navbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky !important;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-navbar">
    <h2>top navbar</h2>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <h1>My navbar</h1>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: there is no element with .navbar class

Comment: Oops, changed it in the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temani has a great solution, but I wanted to point out the reason your solution isn't working. Position [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is "relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor)". In your case, that's the header, and the nav is already stuck to it. However, if you move the nav below the header (as in the example below), you'll see it works:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.top-navbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-navbar">
    <h2>top navbar</h2>
  </div>
</header>

<nav>
  <h1>My navbar</h1>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you only want to keep the `nav` visible on scroll. In this case do it like below. Move sticky to `header` and consider a negative value for `top` equal to the height of `top-navbar`

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: -100px;
}

.top-navbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  background-color: orange;
}


h1,h2 {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-navbar">
    <h2>top navbar</h2>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <h1>My navbar</h1>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works